# How should I investigate an exterior leak from bathroom shower use?

Tags: plumbing

I noticed after a shower if I go outside that there is water leakage coming out of the stucco wall.  Should I start to investigate going under the house for the leak or cut a square out where the leakage seems to be outside.  Or inside the bathroom shower wall?

Comment: Is your house on a slab or is there a basement?

Comment: A photo would really be helpfully here I can think of all kinds of crazy answers but a photo would be helpful,

Answer (score 3):

You can do some investigation without opening up a wall:

(1) Fill up a  2-gal bucket at some other faucet in the house or outside. Pour this into the shower and then look for the water leak you've been seeing. If you see the leak, then the leak is in the shower pan or the drain.

(2) Run the shower into the bucket so as to catch all the water and none goes down the drain. If you see the leak, then the leak is in the water supply past the shower valve.

**EDIT** It might take more than 2 gal to get the leak to show. You might have to use two 2-gal buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-destructive investigation is to be preferred as a first step. If it's easy to get under the house, do that first. Look for damp, stains, running water, etc., where they should not be.

A shower drain will exit below the floor level of the shower (due to well- known properties of water) so if the leak is above the floor level it is probably coming from the plumbing that feeds the shower head, or a leak in the shower walls.

Such problems are usually addressed from inside (disassembling the shower wall and replacing it with a new one.) or by fitting new plumbing on the surface if you are budget-constrained.